# FlsAlloc cannot be found in KERNEL32.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-xp

I tried to install dotNetFx45_Full_setup (Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview), but I get "FlsAlloc cannot be found in KERNEL32.dll", can I patch somehow KARNEL32.dll? maybe I need Windows 7?

Comment: Are you sure it's not kernel32.dll?

Comment: This is a preview of what's to come in VS11, it no longer supports developing C/C++ apps that can run on XP.  The CRT hard-binds to FlsAlloc() instead of hoping to find it with GetProcAddress().  Plenty of flak about this, it might change at RTM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .Net 4.5 Developer Preview only supports Windows 7.

The [requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27541) state:

> **Supported Operating Systems**: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> - Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)
> - Windows Developer Preview (x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server Developer Preview (x64)

I would suspect that that will change before release.

Comment: +1 and nuked my answer; yours is better. Though I'm not so optimistic as you about that changing before release.